# Please help me out to figure what is making my Functions Slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Using Unit of Work Repository pattern

private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

```
private Entities _Entities = new Entities();

var filing_xml = unitOfWork.T_FILING_XMLRepository.Get().Where(a =>
    a.filing_id == filingID).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is taking around 10 seconds to fetch data

```
var filing_xml = _Entities.T_FILING_XML.Where(a => a.filing_id == filingID).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is taking around 2 seconds to fetch data

Is there any solution to make the unit of work faster?

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = "")
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        return orderBy(query).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

The unit of work class

```
public GenericRepository<T_FILING_XML> T_FILING_XMLRepository
{
    get
    {
        if (this.t_filing_xmlRepository == null)
        {
            this.t_filing_xmlRepository = new GenericRepository<T_FILING_XML>(context);
        }
        return t_filing_xmlRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: The "pattern" is not making your SP slow. Please post your UOW class.

Comment: hi mxmissile .. have updated code adding UOW class

Comment: For the case #2 (the one taking 2 seconds), can you verify if you have an index on the filling_id column? If you already have one, can you post the SQL using SQL Profiler?

Comment: @JonathanMagnan thanks jonathan for your response. I had the index, but the problem was i was getting all the data by .get() so have lot of files and then filtering it. I solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code #1**

```
private Entities _Entities = new Entities();

var filing_xml = unitOfWork.T_FILING_XMLRepository.Get().Where(a =>
    a.filing_id == filingID).FirstOrDefault();
```

You are fetching all the records from the database then you filter the result in the application to get only one record. Your Get method has a filter parameter, why not using it?

Using the code below, you will only fetch only one record from the database.

```
var filing_xml = unitOfWork.T_FILING_XMLRepository.Get(a =>
    a.filing_id == filingID).FirstOrDefault();
```